# How do you access a value in a kusto table by row and column number?

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I have a Kusto table `counts` with 4 rows and 3 columns that has the following elements

```
HasFailure  FunnelPhase count_
0   Experienced 172425
0   NewSubs 25399
1   Experienced 3289
1   NewSubs 643
```

I would like to access the 3rd element in the 2nd column and save it to a scalar. I have tried the following code:

`let value = counts | project count_ lookup 3;`

But I am not able to obtain the desired result. What would be the correct way in which to obtain this value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you'll need to order the records in your table (according to an order you define), then access the 3rd record (according to that same order), and finally - project the specific column you're interested in.

e.g.:

```
let T = 
    datatable(HasFailure:bool, FunnelPhase:string, count_:long)
    [
        0,   'Experienced', 172425,
        0,   'NewSubs',     25399,
        1,   'Experienced', 3289,
        1,   'NewSubs',     643,
    ]
;
let 3rd_element_in_2nd_column = toscalar(
    T
    | order by count_ desc 
    | where row_number() == 3
    | project FunnelPhase
)
;
print result = 3rd_element_in_2nd_column
```